# C# Sort a Dictionary by The Numerical value of string (Key)

Tags: c#, dictionary

Interesting question here. I'm trying to *sort* a `Dictionary<string, string>` by *numeric value*. It works in case of `List<string>` but not `Dictionary`, what am I doing wrong here?

```
Dictionary<string, string> s = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
  {   "a",  "a" },
  { "100",  "1" },
  {   "2",  "2" },
  {  "10", "10" },
};

List<string> g = new List<string> { 
  "1", "10", "a", "1000" 
};

var v = 0;

var problem = s.OrderBy(x => int.TryParse(x.Key, out v));

// outputs original order
var works = from c in g
         orderby int.TryParse(c,out v)
          select c;

// outputs sorted order a, 1, 10, 1000
```

Comment: thats not weird, dictionary is based on set theory of which the order of stuff is not considered at all. you can try a `List` of `KeyValuePair` for alternative, though you may have duplicate keys this way.

Comment: You could always use a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` if you wanted to have it sorted.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for a list either, try initializing it in reverse. Reason: `int.TryParse` returns a boolean (whether the parse was successful or not), and you order by that boolean, not by the parsed value.

Comment: Why don't you use a `SortedDictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: I'm using strings, not ints, I actually was using a SortedDictionary but it does not sort strings numerically (1,100,1000,2) I need (1,2,100,1000).

Comment: So you need to pass in a custom comparer to tell it how to sort values.

Comment: Henizi, it DOES work for the List
IOrderedEnumerable<String> (4 items) 
a 
1 
10 
1000

Comment: Only because you've got the list in numeric order already - try putting "2" at the end of the list... it'll still be at the end of the list after your `OrderBy` call, instead of between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var problem = s
  .OrderBy(pair => int.TryParse(pair.Key, out var parsed) 
     ? parsed          // Take Key value as it is
     : long.MinValue); // Treat pair as the topmost
```

Here we try to parse `Key` from the key-value `pair` and in case we fail, we put the pair on the top (I've used `long.MinValue` in order to mix with possible `int.MinValue` key). You may want to add `.ThenBy`:

```
var problem = s
  .OrderBy(pair => int.TryParse(pair.Key, out var parsed) 
     ? parsed          // Take Key value as it is
     : long.MinValue)  // Treat pair as the topmost
  .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key);
```

if you want to sort non-number keys as well as numbers, e.g.

```
  Dictionary<string, string> demo = new() {
    {   "a",  "a" },
    { "100",  "1" },
    {   "2",  "2" },
    {   "b",  "a" },
    {  "10", "10" },
    {   "c",  "a" },
  };
 
  var result = demo
    .OrderBy(pair => int.TryParse(pair.Key, out var parsed) 
       ? parsed 
       : long.MinValue)
    .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key); 

  Console.Write($"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result)}");
```

**Output:**

```
[a, a]
[b, a]
[c, a]
[2, 2]
[10, 10]
[100, 1]
```

**Edit:** if you want to put numerics first, all you should do is to change `long.MinValue` to `long.MaxValue`:

```
  var result = demo
    .OrderBy(pair => int.TryParse(pair.Key, out var parsed) 
       ? parsed 
       : long.MaxValue)
    .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, Elegant as well without the need for a iComparer

Comment: Is it possible to have the numbers first in the order instead of letters? (2,10,100,a,b,c)

Comment: @Marlon Davies: yes, all you should do is to change `long.MinValue` into `long.MaxValue`

Comment: Thanks, that is a flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct, massive problems, that you need to understand.

1. You are not sorting by v. You are sorting by whatever is returned by the comparer passed into the OrderBy call, which in your sample is a bool.
   So, you are doing this:

```cs
var g = new List<string> { "1", "10", "a", "1000" };
var works = from c in g
            orderby int.TryParse(c,out v)
            select c;
// It doesn't work, because int.TryParse outputs [true, true, false, true]
// which is used as a sorting key, which puts the 'a' as the first element,
// because false is sorted before true.
// try with this input:
var g = new List<string> { "10", "1", "a", "1000" };
// and you'll see that the output is ["a", "10", "1", "1000"]
```

So, your sorting function should be `int.TryParse(c,out v) ? v : -1`.
The `-1` could be something different if you need a sorting also on the invalid keys, but that can be addressed by a `ThenBy` after the `OrderBy`.

BUT, you still have a major bug:

2. You are always updating the single variable `v`. If the value is calculated and stored in a shared variable it could easily lead to problems with late evaluation, so you should remove `var v` from the external scope and use

```cs
// the addition of 'var' in the out declaration enables the usage of a separate, new v for each item in the source,
// thus removing the possibility of collisions.
s.OrderBy(x => int.TryParse(x.Key, out var v) ? v : -1);

// if you need to put the alphanumeric keys last, and maybe sorting
// them alphabetically, you can also use something like:
s.OrderBy(x => int.TryParse(x.Key, out var v) ? v : int.MaxValue)
 .ThenBy(x => x) // sorts by the string itself
 ;
```

Comment: Elegant solution, thanks. I only have to assign it to a variable for it to work.
var yess = s.OrderBy(x => int.TryParse(x.Key, out var v) ? v : -1);

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the -1 and the long.MinValue in the solution below?

Comment: @MarlonDavies what do you mean? The `OrderBy` is going to call the function for every item in the enumeration, and is going to sort the result using the value returned. So, you need to provide a value for every string that does not contain a number. You can use a negative value, or int.MinValue, to have the invalid values at the start of the sequence, or something like int.MaxValue to put them last.

Comment: Chiesa, first of all thanks for your input, I really appreciate it. Now I understand a bit better, I'm not a expert that's why I asked. about the -1. Thanks again...